# React Pass all/multiple props to dynamic children - preferably without context

Tags: reactjs

I've found several examples/posts about how to pass ONE prop to dynamic chidren using React such as:

```
return React.cloneElement({this.props.children}, { parentValue: this.props.parentValue });
```

However passing multiple or all props seems to send things into a recursion loop that eventually crashes the app:

```
return React.cloneElement({this.props.children}, { parentValue1: this.props.parentValue1, parentValue2: this.props.parentValue2});
```

or..

```
return React.cloneElement({this.props.children}, {...this.props});
```

Is there an effective way to pass multiple (or all) props to dynamic children? It would seem that if you can for one or more static children, you should be able to if they happen to be dynamic.

Comment: Use React.Children to map over your children see here: https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater/blob/develop/ui/src/components/App.js#L84

Comment: That's the same as `return React.cloneElement({this.props.children}, {...this.props});` and causes an infinite refresh loop until the call stack is exhausted.

Comment: It's not the same, and it's not causing an infinite loop in the code I posted. Try it by mapping over using the `React.Children` helper method.

Comment: It was something else causing the loop. This seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
import React from 'react'
export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

from now any element you put inside container will have container's props

```
<Container><ContactPage /></Container>
// contactPage will have all props from container
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to exclude children from props to pass it further.
I spent lots of hours to understand why I have a loop.
You can read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7692) about this issue

```
render() {
  const { children, ...otherProps } = this.props

  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, otherProps)
}
```